# How can i integrate Android apps with android wear?

Tags: android, webview, manifest, wear-os

I have built an application using an open source app builder (not native android code). Is there a way that i can integrate that code with a wear application ?
The open source app builder uses a webview to layout and does not use native android components but can i make some entry in the app manifest to get this integration ?

My manifest currently has 1 activity that hosts the webview.

Answer (score 1):

Android wear support only Java application, you can find more informations here https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html